# Using javaScript not getting value from dropdown and showing in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel-5

javaScript code:
 Getting data from dropdown and showing into div inner html.

```
  function showcost() {
        var days = document.getElementById("Ddays");
        var Dudays = days.options[days.selectedIndex].text;
        var div = document.getElementById('cost');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + Dudays * 1200;
    }
```

Dropdown code:
onclick calling function `showcost()`

```
<select class="form-control" name="Ddays" id="Ddays" onchange="showcost()">
               <?php $max_days = $HospitalPack->treat_duration + $HospitalPack->recovery_duration;  ?>
                        @for($i = $HospitalPack->treat_duration; $i<=$max_days; $i++)
                         @if($i == $HospitalPack->treat_duration)
                           <option selected="selected" value="{{$i}}{{'Days'}}" >{{$i}}{{' Days'}}</option>
                         @else
                           <option value="{{$i}}{{'Days'}}" >{{$i}}{{' Days'}}</option>
                         @endif
                        @endfor
                </select>
```

div code: here showing data, after calculating values.

```
<div class="huge" id="cost">{{$HospitalPack->treat_duration * 1200 + $HospitalPack->treat_cost}}</div>
```

Above code is doing nothing. I think I'm unable to find mistake.

Comment: Replace `days.options[no.selectedIndex].text` with `days.options[days.selectedIndex].text`.

Comment: It should be `onclick` or `onchange` ?

Comment: Still not working

Comment: It should be `onchange`.

Comment: I did but not working

Comment: can you check any errors in console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144901/discussion-between-giridhari-lal-and-unknown).

Comment: Chat wont work in my machine due to security reasons.

Comment: ohk show can you give me any solution??

Comment: Where does variable `no` come from on this line -> `var Dudays = days.options[no.selectedIndex].text;`?

Comment: yes I replace `no` with `days` but still it is not working. I also replace `onclick` to `onchange` @Morpheus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,'no.selectedIndex' is useless, you should remove the part 'no.'.Maybe you mean this way/??

```
var Dudays = days.options[days.selectedIndex].text;
```

Besides that, when you click the select element the browser would trigger 'onclick'.If you wanna update the view after you select a new option, you need to use 'onchange' instead.
And I prefer you can show me the DOM structure without php codes.

Comment: I made both changes. Is dere anything other ??

Comment: Can you show me the 'Page Source'? You can get it by right mouse button in Chrome

Comment: It's working now but actually in `Dudays` data is like `9 Days` I just want to 9 so can you tell me how??

Comment: Oh, I get it...replace the origin options with: <option selected="selected" value="{{$i}}" >{{$i}}{{' Days'}}</option>
And then: var Dudays = days.options[days.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: That would work. But you need to know the value can be different between with the showing text. https://codepen.io/linjiyeah/pen/GmPBGd  <--normally I do in this way...

Comment: I have 3 dropdown so how can I check from which dropdown I got value??

Comment: The easiest way is saving it in a global variable. like 'window._valueFrom = days;'

Answer (score 0):

javaScript Code:

```
function showDucost() {
        var days = document.getElementById("Ddays");
        var Dudays = days.options[days.selectedIndex].text;
        var pos = Dudays.indexOf("Days");
        var days = Dudays.slice(0,pos-1);
        var div = document.getElementById('Dcost');
        var treat_cost = <?php echo $HospitalPack->treat_cost ?>;
        div.innerHTML = treat_cost + days * 1200;
    }
```

Dropdown code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Ddays" id="Ddays" onchange="showDucost()">
    <?php $max_days = $HospitalPack->treat_duration + $HospitalPack->recovery_duration;  ?>
    @for($i = $HospitalPack->treat_duration; $i<=$max_days; $i++)
    @if($i == $HospitalPack->treat_duration)
  <option selected="selected" value="{{$i}}{{'Days'}}" >{{$i}}{{' Days'}}</option>
  @else
<option value="{{$i}}{{'Days'}}" >{{$i}}{{' Days'}}</option>
 @endif
  @endfor
```

div element code :

```
<div class="huge" id="Dcost">{{$HospitalPack->treat_duration * 1500 + $HospitalPack->treat_cost}}</div>
```